# Objects not showing up when in render view. Only the background shows up

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, orthographic

I have this weird glitch where I can see my objects and scene just fine in object mode. But when I switch to rendered mode or just render my scene nothing shows up except the background. I have tried everything. Enabling the objects in render view, add a new camera and adding new lights. I tried to clear all restric render. But nothing is working.

If anyone wants to take a look at the files go ahead. Please go ahead because I want this to be solved.

Files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xYwxF4vDiq1QDnN9_UMIqz3PRo__zAqm?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your objects have cycle shader and so if you activate Cycle Render as your renderer, it is just fine...

Comment: I wanted to have the gradient background in blender render because it doesnt work in the cycles render. But I wil just add the gradient background in photoshop.

Comment: It's called "Cycles" render engine.